# Cryptic crossword explanation needed ... pay by a quarter to eight

Tags: cryptic-clues

A cryptic crossword clue is given as "Pay by a quarter to eight". 5 letters.  The answer from Wordplays is "screw" and it fits other answers across. But why? I've looked at it forwards,  backwards and upside down but it makes no sense. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 19):

My explanation is

> A **screw** is the pay you are getting - "I am on a good screw."
>  [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/screw) has for **screw**
>  **5** An amount of salary or wages.
>
>  It starts with **S** - south - a compass point - a quarter.
>  [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/quarter) has for **quarter**
>  **5** The direction of one of the points of the compass, especially as a direction from which the wind blows.
>
>  It ends with **CREW** - an "eight" - a rowing crew.
>  [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/eight) has for **eight**
>  **1.5** An eight-oared rowing boat or its crew.
>
>  So that is a quarter **S** + eight **CREW** = **SCREW**.

Comment: This is definitely correct.

Comment: "Pay a quarter by eight" may have been a better clue, as S is "by" crew. Screw is never pay to, just pay or compensation. If anything it means extract payment from - screw it out of them (as in thumbscrews or the like).

Comment: @mckenzm - But if it were changed the way you suggest, the surface sense would be blown. If you are going to do that, you might as well start over and completely rewrite the clue.

Answer (score 0):

According to multiple dictionaries, including [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/screw), a British dictionary, **screw** is chiefly British slang for **salary, wages**, i.e. **pay**. That covers the straight clue.

For the cryptic clue... I'm not sure about the following, but one of the definitions for the Cockney rhyming slang [four-by-two](https://books.google.com/books?id=4YfsEgHLjboC&pg=PA790&lpg=PA790&dq=cockney+rhyming+slang+%22screw%22+%22two%22&source=bl&ots=7LWKO5mZ28&sig=ACfU3U1Wvjz1g5Fdtnz4Vek24NAySIPtDw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiK68bA07vpAhUFbawKHRlIDVEQ6AEwCnoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=cockney%20rhyming%20slang%20%22screw%22%20%22two%22&f=false) is **screw** as in prison office. And four-by-two is dividing eight into quarters.

It's not really satisfying, but it sort of fits.

Comment: "screw" is British slang for so many things: sex, prison warders, ... I'm British and I didn't even know about the "pay" meaning.

Comment: Ah ok. I want familiar with that meaning. Sort of makes sense. Thanks for both answers.